# Animation while waiting for result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make an animation, so as to imitate user waiting for a result. Here is my JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loadingDiv").hide();
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#numb").on('keyup', function () {
            Search(function (){
                $("#loadingDiv").hide();
            });
        });

        $("#desc").on('keyup', function () {
            Search(function () {
                $("#loadingDiv").hide();
            });
        });

        function Search() {
            var nr = $("#numb").val();
            var desc = $("#desc").val();

            $.get('@Url.Action("CircumstanceFiltering", "Administration")', { 
                nr: nr, 
                desc: desc     
            }, function (data) {
                $("#loadingDiv").show().delay(2000);
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

It seems to be correct, but I cant get the idea, why part with `$("#loadingDiv").hide();` does not trigger after `Search()` is completed?
Part of Markup:

```
<div id='loadingDiv'>
    Please wait...  
    <img src='~/Content/themes/custom/images/ajax-loader.gif' />
</div>
```

The `Search()` function itself works well, the only case is that I can not hide this animation after search is completed.

Comment: Search is not using callback function passed.

Comment: Is not it callback function, which has to be triggered after the search is completed?

Comment: It's not a default feature - you have to actually call the function you provide as the parameter. It's quite redundant in this case though - see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually using the anonymous function you provide to the `Search()` function. It's also redundant in this case as both functions do the same thing. The logic for showing the loading indicator also seems to be backwards, as you hide it when the request starts, and show it when it stops. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#loadingDiv").hide();    
        $("#numb, #desc").on('keyup', Search);

        function Search() {
            var nr = $("#numb").val();
            var desc = $("#desc").val();

            $("#loadingDiv").show();

            // you can delay the request by 2 seconds using setTimeout, but I strongly
            // suggest you don't do this. It will just annoy your users.
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.get('@Url.Action("CircumstanceFiltering", "Administration")', { 
                    nr: nr, 
                    desc: desc 
                }, function (data) {
                    $("#loadingDiv").hide();                         
                    $("#result").html(data);
                });
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, this works great. Thank you. The only issue left, why when I add  `$("#loadingDiv").show().delay(2000);` animation still disappears simultaneously?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as `show()` should make the element appear. I'm not clear why you want to delay it appearing for 2 seconds too, as in that case the AJAX request should have ended before the image is even shown.

Comment: mmmm, I thought that putting methods like `method().method2()` they will be chained, so it will appear, then delay for 2 sec, and then request. (I`m very new to JS)

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work like that, but even if it did there's no need to make your users wait 2 seconds before firing the request

Comment: I`m making a copy of existing site, and there is animation with fixed time (about 2 sec) before it shows the result of the request. So I have to make the same, where should this delay method set?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout`. I updated my answer for you, although I would strongly suggest you don't do this, as it will make your site slower for no good reason at all

Answer (score 1):

Just put `$("#loadingDiv").show()` before calling `$.get(..)` and put `.hide()` inside function done() - that should fix it

```
            $("#loadingDiv").show();
            $.get('@Url.Action("CircumstanceFiltering", "Administration")', { nr: nr, desc: desc }, function (data) {
            $("#loadingDiv").hide().delay(2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually passing a callback. But never calling it. You should show the "loader" before $.get and on success you should hide(call the callback).
So try to modify Search with following.

```
 function Search(fnCallback) {

        $("#loadingDiv").show();

        var nr = $("#numb").val();
        var desc = $("#desc").val();

        $.get('@Url.Action("CircumstanceFiltering", "Administration")', { nr: nr, desc: desc }, function (data) {

            $("#result").html(data);
             fnCallback.call();
              //OR 
            $("#result").html(data).promise().done(function(){
                   fnCallback.call();
                  //fnCallback will be get called when data is completely rendered in the page
           });

        });
```

Comment: Hi @GeekyNuns use promise on html() so that animation will not disappears simultaneously